# Error when building tvOS app with asset catalogs populated

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tvos, apple-tv

I'm trying to build a simple tvOS app sample. No built issues if I use asset catalogs without images, but if I add a "Large icon" (1280x768) into an asset catalog, the compiler gives this error after building:

```
The image stack "App Icon - Small" must have at least 2 layers with 
applicable content. Although it has 3 layers, none have applicable content
```

Comment: Thx Glen, for your editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a layered image for the AppIcons as described in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/)